# SXA style option for custom rendering

Tags: sxa, presentation

**What I have done**: I have a new rendering by cloning. I created a component on the basis of a new template created by cloning. On a new partial rendering, I added the newly created rendering and created a component.

**What's the problem**: I am not getting the option for styling. I have added the newly created rendering to some of the existing styles.

Comment: @Peter : Saw that link. Didn't help.

Comment: Can you verify that your component has rendering variants that inherit from IStyling? That is needed to see the styling options.